# Google Maps setTimeout() not working with an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, settimeout

I am building a web app that drops markers on a map based on the viewport bounds. The markers are dropping as expected when the user moves the map, but they drop simultaneously and I would like them to drop consecutively.

To solve this, I am attempting to use the `window.setTimeout()` (as per Google Maps API [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration)) but I am having trouble making it work with my data which is added to a Set by an AJAX call.

I am not too sure how to structure the window.setTimeout() function within my JS code, which is more complicated than Google's example. I have tried dozens of different variations with no success.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
var markers = new Set();
var marker, i;

[...] 

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", () => {
              var lat0 = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
              var lng0 = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng();
              var lat1 = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat();
              var lng1 = map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng();

              $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/electra/marker_info/',
                data: {
                  'neLat': parseFloat(lat0),
                  'neLng': parseFloat(lng0),
                  'swLat': parseFloat(lat1),
                  'swLng': parseFloat(lng1)
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    add_markers(data, i * 200); 
                }
              });
            });

          [...]
function add_markers(ajaxData, timeout) {
        window.setTimeout(() => {
        for (i = 0; i < ajaxData.length; i++) { //puts markers in the markers set
          if(! markers.has(JSON.stringify(ajaxData[i]))) {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(ajaxData[i][2], ajaxData[i][3]),
                map: map,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              })

             [...]

              markers.add(JSON.stringify(ajaxData[i]));
            }
          }
        }, timeout);
      }
```

Comment: Can you clarify: you would like to have each single marker dropped after a `timeout` ? So for instance, every `timeout` interval, add a marker to the map

Comment: I would like the markers to drop one after the other rather than all at once (currently huge batches of markers drop at once). According to Google docs this is achieved with ``setTimeout()``

Comment: there is an [example of this in the google maps documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration)

Comment: I'm aware of the example (I link to it in my question) but I was unable to figure out the problem with reference to the docs. If I could I wouldn't take people's time here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have a single timeout for all the markers.

There is an example in the documentation: [Marker Animations With setTimeout()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-animations-iteration) which includes a `setMarkerWithTimeout` function:

```
function addMarkerWithTimeout(position, timeout) {
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    markers.push(
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      })
    );
  }, timeout);
}
```

that can be used in your code, but you will need to change the `markers` array it uses, as you have a `markers` array that contains different data and which is used for a different purpose (you can probably remove the `markers.push` from that function if you don't need references to the `google.maps.Marker` objects).

```
function add_markers(ajaxData, timeout) {
  for (i = 0; i < ajaxData.length; i++) { //puts markers in the markers set
    if(! markers.has(JSON.stringify(ajaxData[i]))) {
      addMarkerWithTimeout(new google.maps.LatLng(ajaxData[i][2], ajaxData[i][3]), timeout);

      [...]

      markers.add(JSON.stringify(ajaxData[i]));
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change your `add_markers` function in this way:

```
function add_markers(ajaxData, timeout) {
  for (let i = 0; i < ajaxData.length; i++) { //puts markers in the markers set
    if(! markers.has(JSON.stringify(ajaxData[i]))) {
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(ajaxData[i][2], ajaxData[i][3]),
          map: map,
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      })
      [...]
     
     // here you increase the delay based on current number or markers
     addMarker(JSON.stringify(ajaxData[i]), timeout * markers.size);
  }
}
```

and define a new function to insert a marker at the wanted time:

```
function addMarker(marker, interval) {
  setTimeout(function() { markers.add(marker); }, interval);
}
```

Basically you move `setTimeout` to the function responsible of actually inserting the marker from the function processing the data you get from the Ajax call.
The line below, will make sure that the first marker will be inserted immediately (`marker.size` being 0); the next ones will be inserted with a `timeout` distance from each other.

```
addMarker(JSON.stringify(ajaxData[i]), timeout * markers.size);
```